# Parallel aplication of the function on pytorch cuda tensor strings

Tags: parallel-processing, gpu, pytorch

I need to apply user defined function to all strings of cuda tensor. Because of that function takes very a few of GPU resources but significant time I want to speed up the calculation applying that function to the several strings contemporaneously. The calculation for different string could take significantly different time. What is the most efficient way to do that?

Comment: Will python's `Multiprocessing` module work for you?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it is. Moreover Pytorch has it's own wrapper around the native multiprocessing module. And it allows me to create several processes in a time. But looks like I lose more time while copying and memory allocaton than win due the multiprocessing, because the calculation for every string of tensor is really tiny )